# Enabling USB debugging mode on Reh Hat Linux

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, redhat

I am currently using RHEL 5 and need to connect my Nexus 4 to my PC with USB debugging enabled (done) so that I can run my android projects directly on the phone rather than the emulator which is very slow and painfully time consuming. I have updated my Android SDK manager and noticed that I did not find any Google USB drivers as those available in Windows. Some more Googling and I came across some steps to be followed to accomplish this in Ubuntu:
1. `sudo lsusb`
2. get the two hex values sepearetd by a ':'(This is the manufacturerID:deviceID you need to tell the system to handle)
3. Then as root, do the following:
sudo su -

```
cd /etc/udev/rules.d
vi 51-android.rules
```

In this file, add a line that enables you to handle your device. Problem is: I do not have this file in my rules.d folder. So what is the procedure for making my device recognizable in any other linux distro (in my case RHEL 5).

Also, when I do this :

```
adb devices
```

output:

```
List of devices attached 
????????????    no permissions
```

Please Help. Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the permissions of adb executable to be able to access usb. 
Try first, if adb works properly, when using it with root permission:

```
sudo ./adb kill-server
sudo ./adb start-server
sudo ./adb devices
```

If you do not have 'sudo' installed on your system, just do the operations above with the root user. If it works, you can use the following workaround to make it work permanently:

```
chown root:user_group adb
chmod 4550 adb
```

After this it should work.

Comment: Thanks Alex I verified using your commands and the adb utility works just fine. Howevere, it still isn't able to recognize my device. I am using RHEL 5. Is that a problem or have I made a mistake in the line I have added to the freshly created file (51-android.rules): SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1004", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
 what does plugdev mean here? Is it a usergroup name or some keyword? Please correct me if my values are wrong. 1004 indicates LG, i took it from the developer site

Comment: Done. Worked !! I had not run the commands as root. Now it's able to recognize my device. Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to create the file from scratch and insert the line, otherwise it won't work.

Follow the instructions that you have found and you are safe.

The adb devices will show your device properly if you follow the steps.

Comment: I created the file and added the line: SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1004", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"   1004 is LG. However, adb is still unable to recognize my device :(

Comment: Don't forget to do `chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` and replug your device

Comment: I did that but still the adb is unable to recognize my device. Is there anything wrong with the values I am using such as the GROUP field? I don't know what "plugdev" means?

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this problem too, when using RHEL/CentOS 6.6, where no `plugdev` group is present.

I run `adb` with unprivileged user account `myuser`.

My solution was to create the `/etc/udev/rules.d/50-android.rules` file with the rules:

```
# udev rules for USB android devices

# samsung: 04e8
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666", GROUP="myuser"

# LG: 1004
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1004", MODE="0666", GROUP="myuser"
```

After which I did (as root):

```
udevadm control --reload-rules ; udevadm trigger
```

and then, as `myuser`:

```
adb kill-server
adb devices -l
```

The explanation: the `GROUP=` option in the udev rules file specifies the group which will own the device when plugged in. In Debian-based distributions there is a `plugdev` group which fulfills this purpose, but some newer RHEL-based distros don't have it. This creates a permissions problem when `adb` is run with a regular (non-root) user, since it won't have access to the devices.

The solution is to assign the USB devices to a group which exists, and to which your linux user belongs. In my case I chose to assign the device to my user's "personal" group, to which it has the proper permissions.

Another solution (untested, but should work the same) would be to create the `plugdev` group and add your user to it.